# Combining DrawerNavigator and TabsNavigator without "nesting" in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on a react native project where I want to be able to use the `TabsNavigator` along with `DrawerNavigator` at the same time. I know that **nesting** navigators accomplishes this but not exactly in the way I want. Nesting navigators will for instance only contain the `TabsNavigator` in one screen of `DrawerNavigator` or the opposite, depending on which navigator you nest inside the other. But I want the tabsNavigator and the drawerNavigator to always be visable, no matter what screen you're in.

I also want the navigators to use the **same screens** and not create new ones with the same name. For instance, if tabsNavigator contains the screen `Reminders`, then drawerNavigator should also contain that screen. But if I'm correct when you declare **`<Tabs.screen>`** or **`<Drawer.screen>`** with the same name and the same component, this creates two separate screens even if they're using the same component.

Example tabsNavigator:

```
const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const TabsNavigator = ( navigation ) => {
  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator>
        <Tabs.Screen name="Calendar" component={Calendar} />
        <Tabs.Screen name="Reminders" component={Reminders} /> 
        <Tabs.Screen name="Weather" component={Weather}  />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
    );
};
export default TabsNavigator;
```

Example drawerNavigator:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function DrawerNavigator() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Calendar" component={Calendar} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Reminders" component={Reminders} /> 
        <Drawer.Screen name="Weather" component={Weather}  />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default DrawerNavigator
```

and now in app.js I would like to do:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
       <TabsNavigator />
       <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

But above code will return the following error:

> Error: Another navigator is already registered for this container

And that is understandable since you can't have multiple navigators inside one `<NavigationContainer>`, hence the use of nesting navigators inside each other, however as I mentioned nesting navigators (which I have already tried) doesn't allow the use of both navigators simultaneously for all screens. There has to be a better way to accomplish this right?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Source:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Ps.
I noticed this is a duplicate of
[Combine TabNavigator and Drawernavigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144803/combine-tabnavigator-and-drawernavigator) but since that post is old and has not yet been answered, I'd like to give this another shot.